# Why does Internet Explorer crash whenever I browse to a SharePoint site?

Tags: error, internet-explorer

On my Windows Server 2008 machine, IE is crashing whenever I browse to a SharePoint site. A dialog appears with the title "Internet Explorer has stopped working". I also receive a message in the tray:

> **Internet Explorer was closed**
>
> To help protect your computer, Data
>   Execution Prevention has closed
>   Internet Explorer. Click to learn
>   more.

It was working before I installed updates from Windows Update.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the installation of KB977724 when Office 2007 applications are also installed on the machine. There are further details about this problem [on the Office Sustained Engineering site](http://blogs.technet.com/office_sustained_engineering/archive/2010/03/11/issues-with-office-after-installing-kb977724.aspx).

A hotfix to this hotfix can be [downloaded from Microsoft Download Center](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/6/2/A624F8C9-B51E-4CC6-A0AC-ACB684E2E265/office-kb980210-fullfile-x86-glb.exe).